# How to share information across views / keep global state in TornadoFX

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I am new to TornadoFX (or JavaFX for that matter), and I'd like to build an application such as the following mockup:

[image]

That is, I want to be able to open a resource file (e.g. a ZIP file) and display its contents in a treeview, with a preview pane on the right.

I've structured the UI in Views so that it looks like this:

[image]

And this would be my `MenuView` class handling the File/Edit menus:

class MenuView : View() {

```
 private val menuController: MenuController by inject()

    override val root: Parent =
            menubar {
                menu("File") {
                    item("Open").action {
                        menuController.openFile(
                                chooseFile("Select file",
                                        arrayOf(FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("File", "*.*"))
                                ).first().path
                        )
                    }
                    separator()
                    item("Quit").action {

                    }
                }
                menu("Edit") {
                    item("Edit 1")
                    separator()
                    item("Edit 2")
                }
            }
}
```

But I don't know how to make the result of my `FileChooser` available to the rest of parts of the UI. My gut would tell me to create it so that:

MenuView - MenuViewController - FileHandler

so that `FileHandler` is a model layer, shared globally across the app. However I don't know how to keep this global object so it cant be injected by TornadoFX DI solution.

What am I missing here? how can i make this file (which my entire application revolves around) globally to be able to work with it in all parts of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using scopes? https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/part2/Scopes.html, There are examples explaining exactly what you are looking for there. Give it a try first.